# How to improve Location accuracy of network provider? Android

Tags: android, locationmanager

I want to trace  the location of my phone and can manage it without problems if I try to get the location by GPS_Provider.... also with a good accuracy, well no problem you think...well If I'm in a building sometimes we don't have a GPS signal and for that reason I want to implement Network_Provider. Tha't also no problem but if I look to my accuracy I have saw an accuracy of 700 meters... well that's to much and I don't like it.

Is there a way to get the accuracy better with only a netwerk_provider?!

Hope someone can put me at the right track!

Comment: You really need to edit your title, which sounds like you want to reduce the accuracy.

Comment: hmmm cant you add the reuslt with some constant?

Comment: hi Alexander...well in fact that's what I want! I understand is what you get is what you get.... so if GPS is given no updates (because we are in a builing) we can't get it better.... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The accuracy you get with NetworkProvider is based on the size of the mobile cells and the number of wifi base stations in Google's database of cells and wifi stations. What you get is what you get. You have no control over this. You'll get better accuracy in the center of a city, where the cell sizes are smaller and there are more wifi base stations. In the country you can get 2500 meters accuracy or 5 kilometers accuracy or more.

Of course, you can filter out location callbacks that have an accuracy that exceeds a certain threshold (if that is what you want to do).

Comment: hi David, Thanks for your reply. If I understand your answer right... If the GPS is given no update (because we are in a building) you get what you get.... and can't make the accuracy better then that... Do I understand it right?! Thanks again

Comment: That's correct. If you are in a building, then you get whatever the NetworkProvider can give you. You can't do anything to improve the accuracy. If my answer was helpful, please accept it by clicking the green checkmark.